# iOS text popup with clickable links

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I'm looking for a simple solution to presenting popup text in an iOS app that contains text with hyperlinks.

At the moment, my text pops up as a UIAlertView. The user has a 'Close' button below which dismisses the box. However, this class (UIAlertView) doesn't allow the use of hyperlinks within the message text. I understand that creating a whole new custom UIAlertView is frowned upon (not to mention probably overkill for what I want to achieve).

Perhaps I'm barking up the wrong tree by using UIAlertViews. I'm new to iOS and don't know the scope of what's available. Essentially, I need a dialog (or window) to pop up, containing a string of text, a (close/back/dismiss) button, and possible hyperlinks within the text. Those hyperlinks in turn launch other popups/windows/dialogs of their own.

What I'm working on here is a simple dictionary application. It's a table view containing terms. The terms lead to definitions, and in most cases, the definitions themselves reference other terms. Fairly simple, and if possible I'd like to use standard API classes.

Any wisdom would be appreciated. If I truly have to go down the route of creating my own custom UIAlertView class, then sobeit! In this case, some pointers for lightweight class creation would be appreciated. I'm not looking to add fancy colours or anything, just the ability to click on bits of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to create your own UIView sub-class to do the trick, controlled by a UIViewController subclass. One trick I've used to make it look more like an alert view is to have your main popup view embedded in a fullscreen view with a clear background.

In general, Apple SDKs make it really easy to do standard things (UIAlertView), but if you want to tinker with it (embedded links), you need to do it yourself.